# Why does SWT Table has spaces between columns in Windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, swt

I asked a similar question before (it has all the screenshot and everything):
[SWT Table.setLinesVisible(false) does not seem to work on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013551/swt-table-setlinesvisiblefalse-does-not-seem-to-work-on-windows-7)

After digging deeper, I observed two (surprising) things:

1. It actually has nothing to do with setLinesVisible() as I
   initially assumed. Those dark column dividing lines are not "lines",
   in fact, if I setLinesVisible(true) using a light color, I'll see
   that the dark "lines" are to the left of the lines. In other words,
   it appears the reason that those dark dividers exist is because the
   background the column cell is not fully filled, it looks like there's
   1 or 2 pixels at the right end of the cell that's not properly
   painted to the desired cell background but is instead showing the
   table background color.
2. If I switch to an (much) older swt jar (talking about 3-5 years
   old), then that "crack" doesn't show up.

So this undesirable behavior only happens with newer swt jars on windows7.

Can someone please advise?

Comment: Isn't that one of those bugs? [table or tree grid lines cover part of selection in win 7](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=303573) or [Tables: empty lines should not have a grid](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=250653)

Comment: Not sure they are the same issue, but they do look very related. I've filed a SWT bug report.

Comment: My bug report is filed @ https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352042  However, nobody seems to have taken the time to look at it...

Comment: It will probably take a time, you can try to write some post on [swt forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=100)

Comment: Thank you! If you post the comments above into an answer I'll choose it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that one of those bugs? [Table or tree grid lines cover part of selection in win 7](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=303573) or [Tables: empty lines should not have a grid](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=250653).

If not, you can write some post on [swt forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=100).