# How to hide lines between cell in JFACE TableViewer?

Tags: jface, tableviewer

I have search in various places but it seems this is not possible to hide the lines between colums or rows. I want to modify the appearance, not to delete a column or a row.
Do you have an idea or a place to search ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Table` `setLinesVisible` method controls the visibility of the lines:

```java
TableViewer viewer = .... your viewer

viewer.getTable().setLinesVisible(false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! Indeed you can get access to the underlying SWT resources managed by JFACE to gain finest control on the various constituents involved. It works fine except that it just hides horizontal lines and not vertical one (between two columns). 

Is it possible to hide these lines ? I have found this :
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=165033
It seems then that there is a "limitation" due to my windows OS (Windows 7 pro) ...

A suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following answer it gives a workaround that works fine for me : [SWT Table.setLinesVisible(false) does not seem to work on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013551/swt-table-setlinesvisiblefalse-does-not-seem-to-work-on-windows-7)
Si I close this discussion.